# Connection close does not close the connections in Tomcat

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, tomcat

In my java web project which runs on Tomcat there are over 4000 sleeping connections after 2 day (I checked them with sp_who command). I do close every statement, resultset and connections after I do a database job. I use the below template for database stuffs.

```
    try{
        this.openConnection();
        this.createStatement();

        // things ...

        this.cleanResources();
    }catch (SQLException e){
        this.cleanResources();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void cleanResources() {
    try {
        if (this.rs != null) {
            rs.close();
            this.rs = null;
        }
        if (this.stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
            this.stmt = null;
        }
        if (this.conn != null) this.closeConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (this.conn != null) this.closeConnection();
    }
}

   public void closeConnection() {
    try {
        if (this.conn != null)
            this.conn.close();
        this.isOpen = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void createStatement() {
    try {
        if (!this.isOpen) this.openConnection();
        this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void openConnection() {
    try {
        this.conn = ds.getConnection(); // ds is a javax.sql.DataSource instance
        this.isOpen = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After every time a sql code worked, the row counts which has sleeping status does increases and the database stuffs gets so much slower. Why does it happens? How can I completely kill a connection after I done with it? Is it really the sleeping connections that makes slower my SQL Server?

Here is my Tomcat configurations(In context.xml):

```
maxTotal="20" maxActive="20" maxIdle="20"
```

Comment: Strongly recommend you get rid of that code and start using try-with-resources instead. Keeping `Statement` and `ResultSet` in fields is not appropriate. --- But, if you insist on that logic, at the very least you need to put `cleanResources()` in a `finally` block.

Comment: Since we can't see what the `openConnection()` and `closeConnection()` methods do, how can we say whether you're doing it right?

Comment: @Andreas I am sorry, I missed that one and now edited.

Comment: @Andreas I am going to try to do it in finally block now.

Comment: @Andreas Doing it with finally blocks did not make any difference, still sleeping connection counts are icreasing.

Comment: No idea what you did, and still no idea what `openConnection()` does, so was that comment supposed to elicit further help?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please share the code for `openConnection()`and `createStatement()`. Keeping JDBC resources such as `Statement` or `ResultSet` as class-level variables is an antipattern and should be avoided because it easily leaks these resources. Instead, these should have minimal scope (method-local variables) and they should be opened inside a `try-with-resources` statement.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I added them, where am I exactly doing wrong? Can you see anything else than closing things in finally part, cause now I am doing these in finally part but it did not make any difference. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where are you toggling the value of `this.isOpen`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I just updated the code.

Comment: OK. Are those methods used from other classes, as well? Is it possible that there are extra `openConnection()` calls without a matching `cleanResources()`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I actually check all of them almost 10 times. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your code / pattern for cleaning connections is flawed:

```
try {
    this.openConnection();
    this.createStatement();

    // things ...

    this.cleanResources();
} catch (SQLException e){
    this.cleanResources();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This doesn't close connections if "things" throws some exception that is not an `SQLException` or subclass.

If should be:

```
try {
    this.openConnection();
    this.createStatement();

    // things ...

    this.cleanResources();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    this.cleanResources();
}
```

Then this:

```
public void cleanResources() {
    try {
        if (this.rs != null) {
            rs.close();
            this.rs = null;
        }
        if (this.stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
            this.stmt = null;
        if (this.conn != null) this.closeConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If either `rs.close()` or `stmt.close()` throws an exception, then the connection is not closed.

It should be something like this:

```
public void cleanResources() {
    try {
        if (this.rs != null) {
            rs.close();
            this.rs = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (this.stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
            this.stmt = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (this.conn != null) this.closeConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Either of these flaws could result in leaking of database connections in some cases.

Another possibility is that somewhere in your code you are not following your (flawed) pattern.

I think you need to read up on:

- Java 7+ "try with resources" support
- Java 1.0+ "try ... finally".

---

It is also worth noting that it is bad practice to:

- catch `Exception` ... in most cases
- squash exceptions (i.e. catch and silently continue) ... in most cases
- scatter calls to printStackTrace throughout your code.

Comment: I observed it, even there were no exception, the sleeping connection counts were increased. And I just tried it with cleaning resources in finally block but it did not make any difference.

Comment: In that case you are doing it wrong.  The "finally" or "try with resources" approaches work ... if you do them correctly.

Comment: If you really need help debugging your code, you need to provide an MCVE (with emphasis on the M ... for Minimal)